# jquery input value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript value and jQuery `val()` returns undefined on `keyup` event. Variable currency is a `select` input which I want the value of in the `convertCash` function.
My code sample is below:

```
    var currenciesData = <?php echo $this->currencies;?>;
    var currency = $('#depositCurrencySelect');
    var deposit = $('#depositCashEndInput');
    var cashInput = $('#depositCashInput');

    currency.change(function() {
        convertCash(this, deposit);
    }); 
   //There is the event
    cashInput.keyup(function() {
        convertCash(currency, deposit);
    });

   var convertCash = function(element, elementToChange) {
       console.log(element);
       console.log('value ' + element.value);
        switch(element.value) {
            case 'USD':
                elementToChange.val(parseFloat(cashInput.val() / currenciesData['USD'], 8).toFixed(8));
                break;
            case 'EUR':
                elementToChange.val(parseFloat(cashInput.val() / currenciesData['EUR'], 8).toFixed(8));
                break;
            case 'GBP':
                elementToChange.val(parseFloat(cashInput.val() / currenciesData['GBP'], 8).toFixed(8));
                break;
            case 'BTC':
                elementToChange.val(parseFloat(cashInput.val()));
                break;
        }
   };
```

Thank you!

Comment: did you test with "element.val()" ?

Comment: maybe you should use `console.log` on `elementToChange.val()` and `cashInput.val()` to see if you have something

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you sure is the keyup event and not the change event that is failing? Because i don't know what kind of element is the `'#depositCurrencySelect`, but i think that the `current.change` callback has a bug as `this` is the window object and not the element

Comment: There was a problem with scopes.. I had to call val(), because variable currency is jquery selector. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the `value` of a `select` element. But what you actually want is the value of the selected `option` element.

So use

```
switch(element.options[element.selectedIndex].value)
```

instead of

```
switch(element.value)
```

Note that the value of an option element is not necessarily the same as the text. If you want the text, just use

```
switch(element.options[element.selectedIndex].text)
```

With jquery, you can use

```
switch(element.val())
```

Or, if you need the text,

```
switch(element.find(":selected").text() )
```